# What happens when a Rust struct contains a lifetimed trait?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

Ok, so I'm a total Rust newbie, and I'm experimenting with Rocket. That web framework passes a `Form<MyStruct>`, and I want to transfer that MyStruct into my own custom struct.

```
struct Consumer<T> {
    d: T,
}

impl<T> Consumer<T> {
   fn new(form: Form<T>) -> Self {
       Consumer { d: form.into_inner() }
   }
}
```

That doesn't work of course, I get:

```
the trait `rocket::request::FromForm<'_>` is not implemented for `T`
```

Next attempt:

```
impl<T> Consumer<T> where T: FromForm {
    fn new(form: Form<T>) -> Self {
        Consumer { d: form.into_inner }
    }
}
```

Uh oh:

```
impl<T> Consumer<T> where T: FromForm {
                             ^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

So now I find myself completely unable to fix this! The best I can come up with is:

```
impl<'f, T> Consumer<T> where T: FromForm<'f> {
    fn new(form: Form<T>) -> Self {
        Consumer { d: form.into_inner }
    }
}
```

But that results in this error:

```
51 |           fn new(form: Form<T>) -> Self {                                                                                      
   |  _________^                                                                                                                    
52 | |             Consumer { d: form.into_inner }                                                                                  
53 | |         }                                                                                                                    
   | |_________^ lifetime mismatch
  = note: expected type `rocket::request::FromForm<'_>`                                                                            
             found type `rocket::request::FromForm<'f>`
```

Verifiable example: https://hastebin.com/eqihaqodux.makefile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ensure that you have provided a [MCVE] of what you are trying to achieve. This includes mentioning how you obtained `Form` and `FromForm` (supposing that they come from Rocket, you need to include the `use` statements). The first error message could also be expanded to look like the other two (thus including line numbers and such).

Answer (score 5):

`Form` also has a lifetime parameter. If you tie it to the lifetime of `FromForm`, then you'll move forward a little:

```
impl<'f, T> Consumer<T> where T: FromForm<'f> {
    fn new(form: Form<'f, T>) -> Self {
        Consumer(form.into_inner())
    }

    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

As a general rule, if you return an object that depends on data in another object, then you'll need to link their lifetimes together like this.

At this point, you'll see another error, which conveniently gives you all the information you need to fix it:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:50:17
   |
48 | impl<'f, T> Consumer<T> where T: FromForm<'f> {
   |          - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
49 |     fn new(form: Form<'f, T>) -> Self {
50 |         Consumer(form.into_inner())
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:50:17
   |
50 |         Consumer(form.into_inner())
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The [`into_inner` method on `Form`](https://api.rocket.rs/rocket/request/struct.Form.html#method.into_inner) requires that it's type parameter `T` has the `'static` lifetime, and the error message suggests adding this constraint.

With these changes, it will compile:

```
impl<'f, T: 'static> Consumer<T> where T: FromForm<'f> {
    fn new(form: Form<'f, T>) -> Self {
        Consumer(form.into_inner())
    }

    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you !! I'm still trying to understand Rust lifetimes. Do you happen to know why Form<T>.into_inner() needs 'static on T?

Comment: @TechieSprout I am not really familiar with Rocket, so it's hard to say. It's possible  that it absolutely makes sense when you look deeper. It's also possible that it's there as a workaround for some deficiency in Rust's type system - which may or may not still exist. It could be worth asking about it via one of their [official channels](https://rocket.rs/guide/#getting-help)